# Pandas build fail M1 Big Sur 11.1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, macos

I am using MacBook m1 which is running Big Sur 11.1 ,and I have installed `Xcode-commandline-tools` version 12.3 and it has installed `python3.8.5` and `pip3` .python3 and pip are native apps,that is they run in ARM

`pip3` version `20.3.3`

`python3` version `3.8.5`

`setuptools` version `51.0.0`

`wheel` version `0.36.2`

when I type `python3 -m pip install pandas`
The output is :

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pandas
  Downloading pandas-1.2.0.tar.gz (5.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.4 MB 150 kB/s 
  Installing build dependencies ... error
```

And with a very long list of error about 30,000 lines [(only last few lines)](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Ys89gDyQjP/)

and
`pip3 list` output is

```
cppy            1.1.0
kiwisolver      1.3.1
numpy           1.20.0rc1
pip             20.3.3
pyparsing       2.4.7
python-dateutil 2.8.1
setuptools      51.0.0
six             1.15.0
wheel           0.36.2
```

Is pandas not yet supported or I am doing it wrong and same goes with Matplotlib.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge) for arm64 (Apple Silicon)latest installer here: [installer here](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh)
2. Now create a conda environment for whatever version you have (I'm running 3.9.2)

```
conda create -n cenv python=3.9.2
conda activate cenv
conda install pandas
```

You will drive yourself nuts trying to get all the different packages working if you try to go from wheels/pip, at time of writing.

I think I got pandas working but couldn't get matplotlib working due to kiwi solver issues.  Use miniforge/conda.  This is the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing pandas version 0.25.3. This is the most stable release of Pandas which brings in numpy 1.19.1 which is the most stable version of NUMPY.

try running `pip install pandas==0.25.3`, and it should install the required packages.

Comment: Pandas is @ v1. I don't know the versioning system, but seems like a big difference from standard. Any ideas?